# post xml from iphone to server

Tags: iphone

How can I post XML data format to server?
(I only know post paramters to server)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on the server. You could get the `NSData` `-bytes` representation of the XML data and, if you're working with a RESTful web application, use `PUT` or `POST` when sending the data.